# Bulk rename .jpeg to .jpg

Tags: linux, command-line, batch-rename

I have over 100,000 images in a complicated folder structure similar to the one below:

```
├── folder1
│   ├── 0001.jpeg
│   └── 0002.jpeg
├── folder2
│   ├── 0001.jpeg
│   └── 0002.jpeg
├── folder3
│    └── folder4
│         ├── 0001.jpeg
│         └── 0002.jpeg
└── folder5
     └── folder6
           └── folder7
                ├── 0001.jpeg
                └── 0002.jpeg
```

I would like to keep the folder structure unchanged but I would like to rename each of the .jpeg files to .jpg files (.jpeg->.jpg)

My downstream commands require .jpg files, and attempting to change that code to simply handle the .jpeg files has been unsuccessful.

Comment: You actually mean 'rename' instead of 'convert', I believe. Are you looking for a product suggestion? That'd be off-topic here. Are you looking for a script? If so, you should post what you have so far, because SuperUser isn't a script-writing service.

Comment: It is, apparently, and sadly.

Comment: This has been asked to many times that we even have a tag for it. Looking for the best duplicate and VTC close.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/412450/batch-rename-files-in-linux
http://superuser.com/questions/298407/how-can-i-batch-rename-a-set-of-filenames-in-linux
http://superuser.com/questions/712071/how-to-batch-rename-long-file-names-into-short-ones-under-linux
http://superuser.com/questions/658030/renaming-multiple-files-at-once-with-a-pattern-on-ubuntu
http://superuser.com/questions/220960/batch-renaming-of-files-in-a-directory-using-sed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open the terminal.
2. Change directory to the parent directory of folder1 using the `cd` 
   command.

   ```
   cd /path/to/parent/directory/of/folder1/
   ```
3. Run this command to rename all files with .jpeg extension to .jpg.

   ```
   find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/\.jpeg/\.jpg/'
   ```

The above command uses the Perl `rename` program which is installed by default in Debian-based operating systems. In some other Linux distributions, the same Perl rename program is called *prename*. prename can be installed by following the instructions from: [Get the Perl rename utility instead of the built-in rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename).

Comment: It looks like you can use the same command but use mv instead of rename

Comment: The mv does not work here.  On Ubuntu, at least, you can use
"rename.ul .jpeg .jpg *.jpeg" in a single directory.

Comment: For example, within Alpine Linux: `apk update && apk add make perl-utils && cpan File::Rename` will install the Perl version of `rename`.